# python develop non-greedy regex to match specific pattern several times

Tags: python, regex

I am about to develop a regex for a pattern given in a file I want to process.

The file contains several articles, which all follow a similar pattern:

1. start with a line i.e. newline
2. then have some non-word characters on a line followed by "Dokument xx von xx" and a newline
3. that is followed by a body of characters
4. ends with two newlines, followed by a line with non-word characters followed by "Copyright" followed by more characters and a new line
5. one optional line containing non-word characters followed by more characters and a new line
6. finally one line containing non-word characters followed by either "All Rights Reserved" or "Alle Rechte vorbehalten" and a new line

I try to come up with a non-greedy regex, that accurately matches the start, body, and end of the article(s).

For 1-4 I have `^n\W+Dokument.+?[\r\n][\r\n]\W+Copyright[^\n]+\n`

What is necessary for 5-6?

Do I actually need a dotall flag if I aim to use this regex as proposed to match the pattern several times in a file?

I have been on this all day. Can someone with a fresh mind show me the missing bits?

Cheers, 
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

> 5. one optional line containing non-word characters followed by more characters and a new line

```
(\W+?(?:(?!All|Alle).)+?\n)?
```

> 6. one line containing non-word characters followed by either "All Rights Reserved" or "Alle Rechte vorbehalten" and a new line

```
\W+(All Rights Reserved|Alle Rechte vorbehalten)\n
```

Combining 1-6:

```
^\W+Dokument.+?[\r\n][\r\n]\W+Copyright[^\n]+\n(\W+?(?:(?!All|Alle).)+?\n)?\W+?(?:All Rights Reserved|Alle Rechte vorbehalten)\n
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yS0tK6/1)

Comment: Thank you! I will test it soon. Do i need Dotall for this?

Comment: @AndrewTobey yes .. you need DOTALL

Comment: I have tested it with regex101. With dotall enabled, it will match the very first article correctly. But it says "1 match". Is there a config in regex101 to show all matches that I have to enable?? I used "s" as flag.